# Dynamic HTML with Angular JS and google maps infoWindow

Tags: angularjs, infowindow

I got an issue when trying to display some html in an `infoWindow`.

in this example, i want to increment the value of `$scope.number` each time i click on a marker, the problem is that the value is correctly incremented (you can console.log to see it) but the `infoWindow` is still showing 0

PS: I really need to set the `infoWindow` content as a `document.getElementById`

thanks and sorry for my bad english :D

```js
  $scope.number=0;  
  
  $scope.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById("infoWindow")
  });

  
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    
    $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
     
    var mapOptions = {
      center: $scope.position,
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.712215,3.196801),
      map: $scope.map
    });
      
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.759615,2.9286236),
      map: $scope.map
    });
            

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function(){
                
      $scope.number++;
      
      if($scope.infoWindow) $scope.infoWindow.close();
      
      $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map, this);
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function(){
      
      $scope.number++;
      console.log($scope.number);
      if($scope.infoWindow) $scope.infoWindow.close();
      
      $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map, this);
    });
    
  });
```

```html
<div id="map" class="has-header"></div>



<div ng-hide="true">
 <div id="infoWindow">
        {{number}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trigger  `$scope.$apply()` inside your google maps event handler to make the changes to reflect in current scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're incrementing the counter `$scope.number` outside of angular context, you may need to trigger `$scope.$apply();` to reflect the changes in scope.

So inside your google.maps event handler, after you increment the counter `$scope.number++`, call `$scope.$apply();`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function(){

      $scope.number++;

      if($scope.infoWindow) $scope.infoWindow.close();

      $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map, this);
      $scope.$apply();
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function(){

  $scope.number++;
  console.log($scope.number);
  if($scope.infoWindow) $scope.infoWindow.close();

  $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map, this);
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Another hacky option would be to wrap the `$scope.number++` inside `$timeout`. `$timeout` will trigger the `$digest` cycle as well.